# Image tracking without AR/ 3d in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, augmented-reality

We have a big mural on a big wall. It is requested that when viewing this mural on your handheld device, like a smartphone's camera, image overlays should be placed at specific positions within that mural (that mural has left out parts and the respective cutouts should be displayed on top).

Now, AR tries to render any 3d object relative to your input stream (even a plane, its always a 3d space) and its quite wobbly. I wonder if there is a tool that simply recognizes a given graphic in your camera's stream (respecting any transformations or just partly visibility) and using that info, apply the same transformation to an overlaying graphic.

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67788982/1449710) but I feel here is a better place for asking for a tool because I cant find one.

Edit: there are quite many object and face recognition libraries, but none seem to take any input graphic and "target" or comparison and actually let me apply any transformation it might find to another image.